# Cloudformation templates - replace cluster, keep volumes (and VPC)

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I've adapted the ML Cloudformation template (ML 8.08) to separate the VPC, Volume and Cluster resources into their own templates/stacks.  The 2 goals of this were to 1) allow us to keep our data on EBS volumes, but delete the ML Cluster stack to save on EC2 charges while the cluster is idle (weeks, months); and 2) delete all the cluster stack instances and replace them with new ones of a different instance type (to tune the performance).

However, we've hit an issue: the volumes contain hostnames (basically AWS internal IPs) and if you stop the entire cluster and bring up a new one, the cluster is in an unusable state due the IP addresses not matching.  Replacement of a single node works via the autoscaling groups because that will only replace the 1 node (and uses DynamoDB to maintain the second IP address to it gets the same one after a restart).

Looking for advice on if this is possible/feasible or potential other approaches.

Answer (score 1):

THe CF stacks are designed to be totally shut down *without* deleting them.
If you delete them your asking for a lot of 'your on your own'

Instead of deleting the stacks, simply update them setting the nodes-per-zone to 0.
This will scale down to 0 EC2 instances safely, keep the data intact, keep the metadata (in the DDB table) syncronized and whenever you want to wake em up simply update the stack setting some value > 0

There is a lot of convention and non-obvious dependencies if you try to partially reuse the logic but not fully.

And yes if you delete the stack but keep either the volumes or the DDB database around Very Bad Things can happen if you attach those to other clusters --
Very Very Very bad things if you you make a *copy* of the volumes and attach them to different clusters -- Dont Do That.

Comment: It looks like the templates have been updated since we began using them in November (2018) and now have a nodes per zone spec (with a comment on shutdown/hibernate) instead of a total node count spec.  We'll take a look and see if this is something we can adapt.

Comment: Perhaps you got your original templates from elsewhere.  The Nodes-Per-Zone has been in the sample templates from the beginning.   
Note:  these are *sample templates* --- they suffer from working too well that they can be confused with *production templates*, and equally confused with the actual runtime implementation.   The templates only 'configure' reasonable defaults, the underlying feature is "Managed Clusters" -- If you make changes to the templates you need to understand the feature behind them to avoid seriously breaking it (and potential for very behaving deployments.)